# How Can I Retrieve Items From Database to Controllers?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, laravel

I want to retrieve data from my database to my controller and use it my views. I've tried but got an error.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $trans = Uwdlog::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    $rlink = url('/') . '/refer/' . Auth::User()->username;
    $package = Package::first();
    $user = User::find(Auth::User()->id);
    $avatar = Avatar::where('user_id', $user['id'])->pluck('photo')->first();
    $refers = User::where('refid', $user['id'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    $balance = DB::select('select * from student');

    return view('home', compact('trans', 'rlink', 'refers', 'package', 'avatar', 'balance'));
}
```

**home.blade.php**

```
@extends('front.layouts.master')

@section('content')
<!--Start Admin Section-->
<section class="admin-two dashboard">
<!--Start Container-->
<div class="container">
<!--Start Admin Wrap-->
<div class="admin-two-wrap">
<!--Start Admin Wrap Row-->
<div class="row">
<!--Start Admin Menu Col-->
@if ($balance == null)
do this

@else
@include('front.layouts.sidebar')
<!--End Admin Menu Col-->
@endif
<!--Start Admin Content Col-->
<div class="col-md-9">
<!--Start Admin Content-->
<div classs="admin-two-cont">
<!--Start Dashboard-->
<div class="admin-dashboard">
<!--Start Row-->
<div class="row">
<!--Start Overview-->
<div class="db-overview">
<!--Start Overview Item Col-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <!--Start Overview Item-->
  <div class="overview-item {{Auth::User()->package_id == '1' ? 'two': 'one'}}">
      <h3 class="text-center">{{Auth::User()->firstname}} {{Auth::User()->lastname}}</h3>
      <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
      <p class="text-center">{{Auth::User()->package_id == '2' ? 'Premium': 'Free'}}</p>
  </div>
  <!--End Overview Item-->
</div>
<!--End Overview Item Col-->

<!--Start Overview Item Col-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <!--Start Overview Item-->
  <div class="overview-item three">
      <h3 class="text-center">Balance</h3>
      <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i></p>
      <p class="text-center">{{ number_format(floatval(Auth::user()->balance) , $gset->decimalPoint, '.', '') }} 
{{$gset->curSymbol }}</p>
  </div>
  <!--End Overview Item-->
</div>
<!--End Overview Item Col-->

<!--Start Overview Item Col-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <!--Start Overview Item-->
  <div class="overview-item three">
      <h3 class="text-center">Refered User</h3>
      <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-share"></i></p>
      <p class="text-center">{{count($refers)}} Person</p>
  </div>
  <!--End Overview Item-->
</div>
<!--End Overview Item Col-->

<!--Start Overview Item Col-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <!--Start Overview Item-->
  <div class="overview-item {{Auth::User()->package_id == '1' ? 'four': 'one'}}">
      <h3 class="text-center">Status</h3>
      <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-joomla"></i></p>
      <p class="text-center">Active</p>
  </div>
  <!--End Overview Item-->
</div>
<!--End Overview Item Col-->
</div>
<!--End Overview-->
</div>
<!--End Row-->
<div class="row">
<!--Refer -->
<div class="db-overview">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
<div class="panel-heading">My Referal Link:</div>
<div class="panel-body">

<h3><code>{{ $rlink }}</code></h3>
</div>
</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-info ">
<div class="panel-heading">Package Informaton</div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <table class="table-striped col-md-12">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Package</th>
        <th>Commision</th>
        <th>Daily Limit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Free</th>
        <td>{{$package->frcomm}} {{$gset->curSymbol}}</td>
        <td>{{$package->frlimit}} Person</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Premium</th>
        <td>{{$package->prcomm}} {{$gset->curSymbol}}</td>
        <td>{{$package->prlimit}} Person</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div> 
  </div>

</div>
</div>



<!--Start Row-->
<div class="row">
<!--Start Visitors Country-->
<div class="admin-vistitor-country">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="visitor-country">
      <h3 class="text-bold text-center">Transactions</h3>
      <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-responsive">
              <thead>
                  <tr>

              <th>
                Transaction ID
              </th>
              <th>
                Amount
              </th>
              <th>
                Operation
              </th>
              <th>
                Balance
              </th>
              <th>
                Description
              </th>
              <th>
                Processed at
              </th>


                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
   @foreach($trans as $tran)
<tr class="{{ $tran->flag == "1" ? 'success' : 'danger' }}">
<td>
{{$tran-> trxid }}
</td>
<td>
{{number_format(floatval($tran-> amount), $gset->decimalPoint, '.', '')}} {{$gset-> curSymbol}}
</td>
<td>
{{ $tran->flag == "1" ? 'Credited' : 'Debited' }}
</td>
<td>
{{number_format(floatval($tran->balance), $gset->decimalPoint, '.', '')}}      
</td> 
<td>
{{$tran-> desc}}
</td>
<td>
{{$tran-> created_at}}
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach    
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                      <th>
                Transaction ID
              </th>
              <th>
                Amount
              </th>
              <th>
                Operation
              </th>
              <th>
                Balance
              </th>
              <th>
                Description
              </th>
              <th>
                Processed at
              </th>

                  </tr>
              </tfoot>
          </table>
          <?php echo $trans->render(); ?>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--End Visitors Country-->
</div>
<!--End Row-->
</div>
<!--End Dashboard-->
</div>
<!--End Admin Content-->
</div>
<!--End Admin Content Col-->
</div>
<!--End Admin Wrap-->
</div>
</div>
<!--End Container-->

</section>
<!--End Admin Section-->


@endsection
```

I want to be able to display 'do this' `if balance == null`. I get the error message:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found.

Please help check if I loaded the views correctly.

Comment: sorry...im new to asking questions here, pardon me. the error is unidentified variable balance

Comment: I see that you mention "views" in plural form, are you trying to access that variable in other pages as well (other than the 'home')?

Comment: no, just want to access it in home.blade

Comment: First, change $balance = DB::select('select * from student') to $balance = DB::select('select * from student')->get() and then could you dd($balance); and let us see what you get?

Comment: @MyLibary Adding `->get()` will cause an error. When you use `select()` as the first method in the chain it run the query that is passed to it. It uses the select method on the `Connection` class not the `Builder` class.

Comment: Right, could you dd($balance) and let us see what it contains? Is the part of code you've attached a partial? (means you're using it also in other views?)

Comment: @MyLibary i still got an error

Comment: dd it in the controller it self not in the VIEW.

Comment: @MyLibary please indicate how the code should be

Comment: I'm asking you to debug the balance variable but you're not co-operating. If you change the $balance line to $balance = 2; does the view fail as well?

Comment: yes sir, it still flags error. i'm kind of thinking i didn't load the balance to my views the right way.

Comment: `var_dump($balance = DB::select('select * from student'))` the error clearly says that your variable balance isn't set `unidentified variable balance`

Comment: Share your home.blade.view please

Comment: @MyLibary  i reedited the comments so my home.blade view is there

Comment: Change `DB::` to `\DB::` **or** add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` to the top of your class file (underneath the `namespace` line and before the `class` line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line above your class file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `$balance = DB::select('select * from student');` in your controller. And you may have forget to import the **DB**.

Add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` in your controller head.

You can check for more info in https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#running-queries .